# Have separate activity for swipe tabs

Tags: android, xml, tabs, android-activity, swipe

I am new to android programming and currently i am doing an app with with three tabs like this -

[image]

I followed [this link](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tabs-and-swipe-views/?lang=en) to develop it.

But my current app calls separate XML files for each tabs. I want to call separate activity for each activity.

Please guide me with some materials or tutorials from basic.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to call seperate activity for each activity.

That is not supported. The old activities-in-tabs approach has been deprecated for over two years. You are welcome to use fragments or ordinary `ViewGroups` as the contents of your tabs.

Comment: Thank you for ur feedback.
Pls guide me with some tutorials

Comment: @gouthaman93: The tutorial you link to in you answer shows you one way of implementing swipe tabs using fragments.

Comment: but in the above tutorial it calls an xml file when tab changes.
i wanted a activity to be called not a xml file..

Comment: As @CommonsWare said, its something like you CAN'T do that now, at least you SHOULDN'T.